# how to get only array values into another array

Tags: php, arrays

need to get only array values into an array.
i have array like.

[image]

and want to convert into another array like.

`array('pic','picc','topic');`

i have tried this but it gives me same result

```
$new_array = array();
foreach($tags as $val)
{
    array_push($new_array, $val);
} 
print_r($new_array);
```

Comment: this is the same. also your second array (what you want) will have an index as key.

Comment: Tell us why do you want it?

Comment: If you have a key-array you can use http://php.net/manual/de/function.array-values.php. Buy every array has index numbers.

Comment: is only a different way for show the contenct but are the same arrays  ..

Comment: want to use it in MySQL query $this->db->query("UPDATE `discuss_tags` SET TotalPosts=TotalPosts-1 WHERE `Name` in ".$tags."");

Comment: You want a string then? You can use `implode()`

Comment: then show us the query you are using  .. end eventually the error message

Comment: array('pic','picc','topic'); and other Array are identically same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `implode()` for your query and change the way you implement it:

```
$tags = implode("','", $array);
$this->db->query("UPDATE discuss_tags SET TotalPosts=TotalPosts-1 WHERE Name in ('".$tags."')");
```

The query will look like this:

```
UPDATE discuss_tags SET TotalPosts=TotalPosts-1 WHERE Name in ('pic','picc','topic')
```

PHP Manual: [Implode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php)

Comment: thanks. it works for me i was searching for any keyword that can fill full my requirement. but your answer working perfectly for me.

Answer (score -1):

`array('pic','picc','topic');` such an array only exists in pseudocode, not in PHP.
Arrays in PHP will always have numeric indexes unless you force string indexes.